# Jenkins Ant build failed "src does not exist!"

Tags: java, jenkins, ant

When I run my code in the console, it runs fine. It also runs fine on eclipse. But when I try to build on Jenkins, it is asking for a src folder:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\Work space\job1\src" does not exist!

build.xml

```
<project name="Sample Ant build" basedir=".">
<!-- ========== Initialize Properties =================================== -->
<!-- set global properties for build -->
<property name="basedir" value="." />
<property name="lib" value="${basedir}/lib" />
<property name="src" value="${basedir}/src" />
<property name="bin" value="${basedir}/bin" />
<property name="report-dir" value="${basedir}/Test-Report" />
<property name="testng-report-dir" value="${report-dir}/TestNGreport" />

<!-- ====== Set the classpath ====  -->
<path id="classpath">
    <pathelement location="${bin}" />
    <fileset dir="C:\WebDriver\Selenium">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<!-- Delete directories  -->
<target name="delete-dir">
    <delete dir="${bin}" />
    <delete dir="${report-dir}" />
</target>

<!-- Creating directories -->
<target name="create" depends="delete-dir">
    <mkdir dir="${bin}" />
    <mkdir dir="${report-dir}" />
</target>

<!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${bin} -->
<target name="compile" depends="create">
    <javac srcdir="${src}" classpathref="classpath" includeAntRuntime="No" destdir="${bin}" />
    <echo> /* Compiled Directory Classes */ </echo>
</target>

<!-- Runs the file and generates Reportng report for TestNG-->
<taskdef name="testng" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask" classpathref="classpath" />

<target name="testng-execution" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${testng-report-dir}" />
    <testng outputdir="${testng-report-dir}" classpathref="classpath" useDefaultListeners="true">
        <xmlfileset dir="${basedir}" includes="testng.xml" />
    </testng>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse uses a workspace, Jenkins uses a workspace (and in our case, TFS also uses a workspace). They are not the same thing. (Your query is missing some details to answer authoritatively, some some assumptions were made)

Your build.xml script sets BASEDIR to ".", or the working directory. For a Jenkins job, that is as below - See [Administering Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins):

```
JENKINS_HOME
+- workspace (working directory for the version control system)
 +- [JOBNAME] (sub directory for each job)
```

In your case, `JENKINS_HOME\workspace\[JOBNAME]` is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\Work space\job1`.

My money is that is not where your Eclipse workspace is mapped to.

I would make the following recommendations:

- Develop your code and test it in Your Eclipse IDE. When satisfied, commit to your version control system (VCS).
- Setup Jenkins to pull code from your VCS into the local workspace of your job and build there. As it's separate to your working copy it helps isolate changes and ensures you have committed everything to source control so your builds come from a know, reproducible source.

  - Set JEKNINS_HOME to a location outside of `C:\Program Files ...`; it's bad practice to place data (like source files and a build) in a location from installation binaries. Lots of goods reasons to do so, including security, easier space management, etc.
  - Choose an appropriate location and set the directory configurations for the Master (Jenkins | Manage Jenkins | Configure System; the first 3 values)
  - IF using [distributed builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) (master/node), within your node configuration (Jenkins | Manage Jenkins | Manage Nodes | Configure => Remote Root directory ) to an appropriate location